# inicializar la medida de un array con NULL

Tags: netbeans

Estoy atascado con este tema, en un programa con metodos, incializamos array con valor NULL pues aun no sabemos la medida que va a tener y pedimos por teclado que se indique la medida, me dan este ejemplo que no funciona, pero si introduzco medida=2 el programa pide 4 veces el dato, podeis ayudarme a corregirlo?

```
//Variable global. Array no inicialitzat.
private int[] llistaEnters = null;
//En aplicar disseny descendent, ara cal declarar "lector" com a global
Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
 OrdenarDescendentVariable programa = new OrdenarDescendentVariable();
 programa.inici();
}
public void inici() {
  llegirLlista();
  ordenarLlista();
  mostrarLlista();
 }
 //Mètode amb les instruccions per llegir la llista.
 //El primer valor sera la llargària
public void llegirLlista() {
 System.out.println("Escriu una llista de valors enters i prem retorn.");
 System.out.println("El primer valor indica la mida de la seqüència.");
 llegirMida();
 llegirValors();
}
public void llegirMida() { //Metode que llegeix el primer valor
 //Lectura
 int mida = 0;
 if (lector.hasNextInt()) {
  mida = lector.nextInt();
 } else {
  lector.next();
 }
 llistaEnters = new int[mida]; //Inicialitizació diferida de l'array
}
public void llegirValors() {
  int index = 0;
  while (index < llistaEnters.length) {
   if (lector.hasNextInt()) {
    llistaEnters[index] = lector.nextInt();
    index++;
   } else {
    lector.next();
   }
  }
  lector.nextLine();
 } //La resta de mètodes no canvien ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenos días,
He hecho alguna prueba y el código que nos has proporcionado parece que funciona bien. Si le pongo length 4 me pide 4 valores, y con length n me pide n... No he podido hacerlo fallar. Podría ser que el fallo estuviera en los métodos que no nos pasas? (`ordenarLlista()` y `mostrarLlista()`)

Te dejo el código de las pruebas que he hecho igulamente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    //Variable global. Array no inicialitzat.
    private int[] llistaEnters = null;
    //En aplicar disseny descendent, ara cal declarar "lector" com a global
    Scanner       lector       = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main programa = new Main();
        programa.inici();
    }

    public void inici() {
        llegirLlista();
        //ordenarLlista();
        //mostrarLlista();

        System.out.println("Llista de valors:");
        for (int valor : llistaEnters) {
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
    }

    //Mètode amb les instruccions per llegir la llista.
    //El primer valor sera la llargària
    public void llegirLlista() {
        System.out.println("Escriu una llista de valors enters i prem retorn.");
        System.out.println("El primer valor indica la mida de la seqüència.");
        llegirMida();
        llegirValors();
    }

    public void llegirMida() { //Metode que llegeix el primer valor
        //Lectura
        int mida = 0;
        if (lector.hasNextInt()) {
            mida = lector.nextInt();
        } else {
            lector.next();
        }
        llistaEnters = new int[mida]; //Inicialitizació diferida de l'array
    }

    public void llegirValors() {
        int index = 0;
        while (index < llistaEnters.length) {
            if (lector.hasNextInt()) {
                llistaEnters[index] = lector.nextInt();
                index++;
            } else {
                lector.next();
            }
        }
        lector.nextLine();
    } //La resta de mètodes no canvien ...
}
```

Comment: Vale estoy viendo el fallo, si que funciona, el problema es que como ejecutaba con esta parte el programa no me finalizaba y seguia pidiendo valores, si sigo aplicando metodos me da el resultado que se pide.

Comment: Perfecto! Me alegro de haberte ayudado! Un saludo